# Simple way to visualise odds ratios in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I need help to create a simple plot to visualise odds ratios for my boss's presentation - this is my first post. I am a real R beginner and I can't seem to get this to work. I tried to adapt some code I found online that produced this apparently:

[image: Dot plot]

I wanted to manually enter my ORs and CIs as that's more straightforward, so here's what I have:

```
# Create labels for plot
boxLabels = c("Package recommendation", "Breeder’s recommendations", "Vet’s 
recommendation", "Measuring cup", "Weigh on scales", "Certain number of 
cans", "Ad lib feeding", "Adjusted for body weight")

# Enter OR and CI data. boxOdds are the odds ratios, 
boxCILow is the lower bound of the CI, boxCIHigh is the upper bound.

df <- data.frame(yAxis = length(boxLabels):1, boxOdds = c(0.9410685, 
0.6121181, 1.1232907, 1.2222137, 0.4712629, 0.9376822, 1.0010816, 
0.7121452), boxCILow = c(-0.1789719, -0.8468693,-0.00109809, 0.09021224, 
-1.0183040, -0.2014975, -0.1001832,-0.4695449), boxCIHigh = c(0.05633076, 
-0.1566818, 0.2326694, 0.3104405, -0.4999281, 0.07093752, 0.1018351, 
-0.2113544))

# Plot
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = boxOdds, y = boxLabels)) 

p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1), size = .25, linetype = "dashed") +
geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = boxCIHigh, xmin = boxCILow), size = .5, height = 
.2, color = "gray50") +
 geom_point(size = 3.5, color = "orange") +
 theme_bw() +
 theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
 scale_y_discrete (breaks = yAxis, labels = boxLabels) +
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,5,1) ) +
 coord_trans(x = "log10") +
 ylab("") +
 xlab("Odds ratio (log scale)") +
 annotate(geom = "text", y =1.1, x = 3.5, label ="Model p < 0.001\nPseudo 
 R^2 = 0.10", size = 3.5, hjust = 0) + ggtitle("Feeding method and risk of 
 obesity in cats")
```

Not surprisingly it's not working! Any advice very appreciated as it's doing my head in!Thanks :)

NB. I tried taking the exponent of my CIs and I got this now:

[image]

Does it look more correct? Is it still correct to label my x axis as a log scale? Sorry, I'm a bit confused!

Comment: There is something wrong with your confidence intervals. Can you double check the values. For example, the first entry has a mean OR estimate of `0.941` with CI limits `[-0.179, 0.056]`.

Comment: Also you have some CIs going into the negative which you cannot take the log of (and negative odds don't make sense)

Comment: Hmm ok thank you, that's strange. Doesn't look like I'm going to get this to work anytime soon - I'll go back and check my logistic regression and see if I can figure out what's happening :(

Answer (score 7):

Your confidence intervals are on the log-odds, So you need to transform them to match the odds ratio - so you could use exp function. Although think about it -- plotting these data using the log-scale axis effectively reverses the work you did with the transformations. So if it were me, I would keep everything in log scale in my data, and use coord_trans() and scale_x_continuous() to do the work of transforming the data:

```
df <- data.frame(yAxis = length(boxLabels):1, 
                 boxOdds = log(c(0.9410685, 
                   0.6121181, 1.1232907, 1.2222137, 0.4712629, 0.9376822, 1.0010816, 
                   0.7121452)), 
                  boxCILow = c(-0.1789719, -0.8468693,-0.00109809, 0.09021224,
                               -1.0183040, -0.2014975, -0.1001832,-0.4695449), 
                 boxCIHigh = c(0.05633076, -0.1566818, 0.2326694, 0.3104405, 
                               -0.4999281, 0.07093752, 0.1018351, -0.2113544)
                 )


(p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = boxOdds, y = boxLabels)) + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0), size = .25, linetype = "dashed") + 
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = boxCIHigh, xmin = boxCILow), size = .5, height = 
                    .2, color = "gray50") +
    geom_point(size = 3.5, color = "orange") +
    coord_trans(x = scales:::exp_trans(10)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = log10(seq(0.1, 2.5, 0.1)), labels = seq(0.1, 2.5, 0.1),
                       limits = log10(c(0.09,2.5))) +
    theme_bw()+
    theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
    ylab("") +
    xlab("Odds ratio") +
    annotate(geom = "text", y =1.1, x = log10(1.5), 
                     label = "Model p < 0.001\nPseudo R^2 = 0.10", size = 3.5, hjust = 0) + 
    ggtitle("Feeding method and risk of obesity in cats")
)
```

You should get:

[image]

Comment: James, you are my hero :) Thank you so much, I didn't think of that! It's working beautifully now.

Comment: Ugh I'm confused. Another silly question, sorry! I used exp(coef(fit)) to calculate my ORs, which I though was the log of the odds. How do I interpret the graphical representation above using a log scale for the odds ratios?

Comment: Its tough to say without seeing more - based on what you are providing, the model is probably returning the log odds ratio (since the confidence intervals are in log scale). Taking the exp is probably returning the odds ratio.So you might either take the exponent of your confidence intervals or set your reference line to zero.

Comment: Ah ok. So for my univariate (for each variable I want to plot) I did fit <- glm(BCS_Bin~Amount_breeder,data=dat,family=binomial), then exp(coef(fit)), then confint(fit). But I should have done exp(confint(fit))? That does return positive values.

Comment: Added a revised plot in my original post, would appreciate a quick look to see if it's better. Thanks again!

Comment: I think exp(confint) will work with exp(coeff) snd and results will be odds ratio, not log odds. With the log scale you are showing odds ratio, just on a logrythmic axis.

Comment: In this answer, the poster's original odds ratios have been turned back to log-odds with boxOdds = log(c(...)), surely the same should have been done with boxCILow and boxCIHigh as well?

Comment: Great answer! I will bookmark it!

Answer (score 3):

Great that you fixed the ggplot2 code! But the whole point of this example was to have a log scale for the x-axis to support the interpretation of a relative multiplicative effect estimate (OR, RR, HR, etc) <1 vs >1. Eg, An effect estimate of "0.5" is an equivalent departure form "1" as an effect estimate of "2" (this is more easily visualized on log scale).

Here is a working version of the original code from the example provided at:
'http://www.jscarlton.net/post/2015-10-24VisualizingLogistic/'

```
df <- data.frame(yAxis = length(boxLabels):1,
  boxOdds = 
   c(2.23189,1.315737,1.22866,.8197413,.9802449,.9786673,.6559005,.5929812),
  boxCILow = 
   c(.7543566,1.016,.9674772,.6463458,.9643047,.864922,.4965308,.3572142),
  boxCIHigh = 
  c(6.603418,1.703902,1.560353,1.039654,.9964486,1.107371,.8664225,.9843584)
)


(p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = boxOdds, y = boxLabels)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1), size = .25, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = boxCIHigh, xmin = boxCILow), size = .5, height = 
      .2, color = 'gray50') +
  geom_point(size = 3.5, color = 'orange') +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,7,1) ) +
  coord_trans(x = 'log10') +
  ylab('') +
  xlab('Odds ratio (log scale)') +
  annotate(geom = 'text', y =1.1, x = 3.5, label ='Model p < 0.001\nPseudo 
R^2 = 0.10', size = 3.5, hjust = 0) + ggtitle('Intention to remove box 
turtles from the road')
)
```